# Why won't my div's align? (CSS web design layout)

Tags: css

div class container is used to wrap all other items of the web page, I want to align this container centrally but can't seem to figure out why it isn't working.

edit: I would like the container itself center on the viewpoint and then I want to individually align the items within their own containers.

edit 2: I have figured it out, thanks for everyone's responses. I changed the HTML selector to the body, then changed the display to flex and finally justify-self to align-items.

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html {
display: block;
flex-direction: column;
width: 100%;
justify-self: center;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}

.sub {
position: absolute;
}

.container {
width: 50%;
border: 2px black solid;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-flex;
position: relative;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Notable|Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <h1 id='main_title'>Website Style Specification - 1</h1>
    <body>
        <div class='container' id='color_container'>
            <h2 class='sub'>Colours</h2>
            <div class='color_box' id='color_one'>
                <p>Coal</p>
                <p>#252525</p>
                <p>Background Colour</p>
            </div>
            <div class='color_box' id='color_two'>
                <p>Blood</p>
                <p>#ff0000</p>
                <p>Text colour</p>
            </div>
            <div class='color_box' id='color_three'>
                <p>Crimson</p>
                <p>#af0404</p>
                <p>Borders ad foreground colouring</p>
            </div>
            <div class='color_box' id='color_four'>
                <p>Slate</p>
                <p>#414141</p>
                <p>Element background</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container' id='font_container'>
            <h2 class='sub'>Fonts</h2>
            <div class='font_box' id='font_1'>
                <h3>Notable</h3>
                <p class='normal'>This is how the text will display on the website.</p>
                <p class='italic'>This is how the text will display on the website.</p>
                <p class='bold'>This is how the text will display on the website.</p>
            </div>
            <div class='font_box' id='font_2'>
                    <h3>WorkSans-Regular</h3>
                    <p class='normal'>This is how the text will display on the website.</p>
                    <p class='italic'>This is how the text will display on the website.</p>
                    <p class='bold'>This is how the text will display on the website.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container' id='text_styles'>
            <h2 class='sub'>Text styles</h2>
            <div class='text_box' id='text_1'>
                <h3 id='sub_headings'>This is a sub heading</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>HTML: h2</li>
                    <li>font family: Notable</li>
                    <li>Font weight: 28px</li>
                    <li>Text decoration: underline</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='text_box' id='text_2'>
                <p id='text'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>HTML: p</li>
                        <li>font family: Work sans</li>
                        <li>font weight: 18px</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer></footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on *"it isn't working."*? You need the `.container` to be centered on the webpage or it's contents? Also, adding a piece of HTML that we can see and reproduce your page as a [mcve], would be good

Comment: where`s your HTML?

Comment: Apologies, edited with HTML and more details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

Give the parent element of `container` `display: flex` and `justify-content: center;`  and let flexbox do its magic. This will center the child elements on the X-Axis

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html {
display: block;
flex-direction: column;
width: 100%;
}

body{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;

color: black;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}

.sub {
position: absolute;
}

.container {
width: 50%;
border: 2px black solid;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="container">
HELLO IM THE CONTAINER
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but it just seems to align the content of the container and the container itself is still positioned to the left.

Comment: as you can see in my code snippet the container is centered. `body` should have `display: flex;`and `width: 100%` aswell as `justify-content: center`